# Why local variable visible and accessible after the for loop is finished?

Tags: python

I'm wondering in python, **Why `d` is visible and accessible after the `for` loop is finished?** In `C`, this not possible. Is it valid in python?

```
for i in range(4):
    d = i * 2
print(d)
```

Online compiler link [here](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/KmK9Kc).

Comment: Comparing two different languages with different semantic rules is pretty pointless.

Comment: And in PROLOG you can't even have a variable named `d`.. so ?

Comment: C gives you the option to declare a variable outside your loop, then refer to it inside the loop. Python, by contrast, doesn't have declarations at all -- so if Python followed the rule you propose, it wouldn't be possible to have content inside a block set an initial value for a variable whose scope extends beyond that block. I don't think I'm far off the mark in calling that an absurd result, and thus the syntax you're expecting unreasonable on its face.

Comment: (Unless you were going to *also* change the language to no longer have it be possible to shadow a variable name from an outer scope, but that's a rather nontrivial change as well).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python does not have block-scoped variables. Rather it has function scopes, class scopes and global scopes.

In other words, a variable initialized anywhere in the function is accessible after that point. E.g.:

```
for x in range(2):
    pass
print(x) # <--- x is accessible
```

Or:

```
def f(x):
    if x:
        y = 1
    else:
        y = 2
    return y # <--- y is accessible
```

Comment: There's an exception to your statement "a variable initialized anywhere in the function is accessible after that point". Since Python 3.x, variables used in comprehensions are valid only within the comprehension: ``[x for x in range(10)]; print(x)`` raises a ``NameError`` (in Python 2.7, this outputs ``9``).

Answer (score 1):

## LEGB Rule

The so-called LEGB Rule talks about this. It is called LEGB because the priorities are:

Local → Enclosed → Global → Built-in.

The variable scopes in Python can be:

- **L**ocal: Variables not declared global or assigned in a function.
- **E**nclosing: Variables defined in a function that is wrapped inside another function.
- **G**lobal: Variables declared global, or assigned at the top-level of a file.
- **B**uilt-in: Variables preassigned in the built-in names module.

---

## In your example:

```
for i in range(4):
    d = i * 2
print(d)
```

`d` is accesible because the `for` loop does not mark a new scope, but if it did:

```
def noaccess():
    for i in range(4):
        d = i * 2
noaccess()
print(d)
```

Python says `NameError: name 'd' is not defined`