# How can I use .get() tkinter in another def? Python

Tags: python, function, tkinter, get

My problem is that I need to get the information out of the entry boxes, from another `def` as integer. But I always get the problem that there is no argument inside the entry box, or that I can't transform a string to an integer.

```
from tkinter import *
import os.path
import sys
import logging
#import mainloop
import main_draw_window
Size_Format="px"
def div_edit_window():
    edit_window = Tk()
    edit_window.title(main_draw_window._Projekt_Name+": DIV Editor")
    div_size_format_changer_bt = Button(edit_window, text="It is "+Size_Format, command=div_change)
    div_ending_x_ent = Entry(edit_window)
    div_ending_y_ent = Entry(edit_window)
    div_ending_accept = Button(edit_window, text="Accept", command=div_ending_set)
    div_size_format_changer_bt.pack()
    div_ending_x_ent.pack()
    div_ending_y_ent.pack()
    div_ending_accept.pack()
    edit_window.mainloop()

def div_ending_set():
    div_ending_x = int(div_edit_window.div_ending_x_ent.get())
    div_ending_y = int(div_edit_window.div_ending_y_ent.get())
    print(div_ending_x)
    print(div_ending_y)
```

Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: `div_edit_window()` is a function when you probably want it to be a class.

Comment: Lazy solution: globals. Good solution, but requires more extensive redesign: classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with Python's scopes I talked about them in [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42423526/7237719).

As [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351486/how-can-i-use-get-tkinter-in-a-nother-def-python#comment73766318_43351486) said, you can use global declarations:

```
global foo
```

This is discouraged, *the best use of `global` is no `global` at all*, so I won't explain how it works.

---

The other way to make that work is by using classes. In classes, `def` can use definitions from other functions, just what you want. Normally you can't use them between functions, for example, this will raise an error:

```
def foo1():
    string = 'x'
def foo2():
    print(string)

foo1() #You would expect this to define the string
foo2() #So this can print it... but no.
```

But this will work:

```
class foo:
    def foo1(self):
        self.string = 'x'
    def foo2(self):
        print(self.string)

MyClass = foo()

MyClass.foo1()
MyClass.foo2()
```

## Line per line explanation:

#### First, this line:

```
MyClass = foo()
```

This is actually making what's called an instance of the class. This will allow that each variable, function, or other thing defined in a instance can be accessed, from:

- Outside the same instance, or even outside of the class or any class, by using `MyClass.var`, `MyClass.var()`, etc.
- From the instance, by using `self.var`, `self.var()`, etc.

Think of these in this way: `A` is an instance of a class, which has a method `foo()` and a method `bar()`. Somewhere in the code `foo()` calls `bar()`. If you want to call the `foo()` function from `A` in anywhere in the code use: `A.foo()`. If you had another instance, `B` then to call `B`'s `foo()` you use `B.foo()` and so on. When `foo()` from any instance calls `bar()` from the same instance the line of code is `self.bar()`. So, `self` represents any instance of a class.

#### The other lines

1. This is similar to defining a function, you are telling Python that the next indented lines belong to a class (instead of a function)
2. Define a function with no parameters (self is obligatory in a class, [there is a reason for this](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com.uy/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html))
3. `string = 'x'` for every instance of this class
4. Same as 2.
5. Show the corresponding (with the instance) string `x` in screen.

And then instantiates the class, and calls `foo1()` and `foo2()`

---

Now you can apply that knowledge to fixing your code. If something is unclear I'll edit my question.